# Move Zeros logic break down Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

I am working through this solution that I saw in this discussion section of leetcode and am unable to grasp part of the logic. The name of the game is to move all zeros to the end of a given array in place while maintaining the order of the other numbers. The increment operator inside the index of j is where I am lost because wouldn't that place the non-zero number to the right?

```js
var moveZeroes = function(nums) {
    let j = 0
    for(let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
       if(nums[i] !== 0) {
           //storing the index we are iterating on
           let n = nums[i]
           //changing the index in place to 0
           nums[i] = 0
           //console.log(nums);
           // 
           nums[j++] = n
           console.log(nums);
       }
   }
   return nums;
};

console.log(moveZeroes([0,1,0,3,12]));
```

Comment: `j++` is the postfix increment operator meaning that `j` is incremented after `n` is assigned to `nums[j]`. In contrast, if it was `++j` then `j` would be incremented first and then `nums` would be indexed with the incremented `j`.

Comment: you can read about it here [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Increment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Increment)

Comment: `arr.sort((a, b) => +(a == 0));` ..?

Comment: `nums[j++] = n` is the same as `nums[j] = n; j += 1;`

Answer (score 0):

Remember that j++ is post-increment, so the initial value of j is used to index nums and then j is incremented. If it was ++j then j would be incremented first, then used.

Comment: This is helpful!

Answer (score 0):

### Update

> OP wants to mutate the array, *"Solution A"* deals with immutable arrays and *"Sulution B"* nutates the array.

**Solution A (Immuatable)**

> Try using [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to separate zeroes (ex. `num === 0`) and numbers that are not zeroes (ex. `num !== 0`) into two new and separate arrays. Then use either [`Array.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) or the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to merge them into a single array.
>
> ```js
> // log() is an optional utility function that formats console logs
> const log = data => console.log(`[${data}]`);
>
> // This input array has zeroes everywhere
> const numbers = [0, 1, 0, 0, 3, 0, 12];
>
> const moveZeroes = array => {
>   // With the given array called "numbers"
>   // left = [1, 3, 13]
>   const left = array.filter(num => num !== 0);
>   // right = [0, 0, 0, 0]  
>   const right = array.filter(num => num === 0);
>   // Then arrays "left" and "right" are merged
>   return [].concat(left, right)
> };
>
> log(moveZeroes(numbers));
> ```

---

**Solution B (Muatable)**

> [`Array.reverse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) the array, track the index with [`Array.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/entries), and run it through a [`for...of` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of). If a number isn't a zero, [`Array.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) it out then [`Array.unshift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) it to the beginning of the array. Note, `.reverse()`, `.splice()`, and `.unshift()` are [mutating Array methods](https://lorenstewart.me/2017/01/22/javascript-array-methods-mutating-vs-non-mutating/).
>
> ```js
> // log() is an optional utility function that formats console logs
> const log = data => console.log(`[${data}]`);
>
> // This input array has zeroes everywhere
> const numbers = [0, 1, 0, 0, 3, 0, 12];
>
> const moveZeroes = array => {
>   /* .reverse() the array, track index with
>   .entries(), and loop thru with a for...of
>   loop */
>   for (let [idx, num] of array.reverse().entries()) {
>     /* if a number isn't zero, remove it with 
>     .splice(), then .unshift() it into the
>     beginning of array */
>     if (num !== 0) {
>       array.splice(idx, 1);
>       array.unshift(num);
>     }
>   }
>   return array;
> };
>
> log(moveZeroes(numbers));
> ```

Comment: Part of it is to not use another array and do it in place!

Comment: @Jaimie see update.

Answer (score 0):

Simply Remove All Zeros. Add Removed Zeros to the end.

```js
var moveZeroes = (nums) =>
  (
    nums.toString().replaceAll("0,", "") +
    ",0".repeat(("" + nums).replace(/[^0]/g, "").length)
  )
    .split(",")
    .map(Number);
console.log(moveZeroes([0, 1, 0, 0, 3, 0, 12])); //[ 1, 3, 12, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
```

**NOTE:**

- `(""+nums).replace(/[^0]/g,'').length`: number of 0 in the Array
- `nums.toString()`: To convert array to string we use or we could use the trick of concatenating with an empty string like `""+nums`
- `split(',')`: To convert string into an array
- `map(Number)`: To convert an array of strings to numbers.